# Do I need to buy the game client in addition to Warlords of Draenor Standard Edition purchase?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, battle.net

My question is that if I buy warlords of Draenor Standard Edition as mentioned here:

https://eu.battle.net/shop/en-us/product/world-of-warcraft-warlords-of-draenor

Does this pack include download of a WOD client? Or do I have to explicitly buy client?

Asking this question as I am new to WoW.

Comment: Reason for down vote?

Comment: They probably down-voted because this information is prominently featured on the official site you link to, and/or they're assuming that if you just buy WoD you're an existing WoW player who should know the answer already. I'll give you a +1, though, since it's probably a fair question for a new player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted, you do not need to buy the client separately. It can be downloaded for free with the battle.net application. An important distinction, however, is that Warlords of Draenor is NOT standalone: you must own the base game (World of Warcraft, located here on Blizzard's store: https://eu.battle.net/shop/en-us/product/world-of-warcraft ) to play it. There is a required monthly subscription fee, although starting today it is possible to buy game time via gold (the game's currency, and this service is only available in the USA as of this post).

Comment: from base game you mean battle.net account ?

Comment: No, he means the base game (including all previous expansions): https://eu.battle.net/shop/en-us/product/world-of-warcraft

Comment: ah ok  , got it thanks for the info, so this means i just have to download the previous patches /game and then shift to WOD, or doy wnload a client that is already WOD compatible

Comment: Buying of game time with gold is for now only available in the America region, not yet for Europe.

Comment: @noobie-php Regardless of what expansion you have it'll be WOD compatable and patched.  You'll see max level guys even if you do not have WOD.  You should be able to proceed in either order (WOD then patch, patch then WOD).  One will probably be more logical for you depending on what order you purchase(d)/install(ed).

Comment: The previous games - vanilla through Mists of Pandaria - is usually available from Blizzard in a "battle chest" for like 20 bucks (or some other heavily discounted price).

Comment: All previous expansions are included in the battle chest, which is currently on sale through Blizzard's official store.

Comment: @Omegacron; lol now what is battle chest?

Comment: @originaluser: What is battle chest?

Comment: https://eu.battle.net/shop/en-us/product/world-of-warcraft This is the battle chest. I'll edit it into my post.

Comment: @noobie-php - The "Battle Chest" is Blizzard's name for a game collection. They have one for all three of their flagship products (Diablo, StarCraft, WarCraft) and it usually includes the game as well as any expansions. The WoW battle chest is updated about a year after each expansion comes out, so that it usually includes all expansions up to the current one. That way, you can catch up by buying the Battle Chest and then the latest expansion.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to buy the client.

The client is completely free and can be downloaded via the battle.net "app". You would not even need to buy the game to download it. But you need to in order to play it of course.